# How to apply a custom mask into a string of digits in Python?

Tags: php, python, masking

Given a custom mask like `##/##/####` or `(###) ###-####` and a string of digits that has a length equals to the number of `#` of the custom mask,

### How can a define a function called `format` that applies a custom mask to a string?

For example:

```
> format('##/##/####','13082004')
13/08/2004
```

In **PHP** I can use `vsprintf` to achieve this:

```
function format($mask,$string)
{
    return  vsprintf($mask, str_split($string));
}

$mask = "%s%s.%s%s%s.%s%s%s/%s%s%s%s-%s%s";
echo format($mask,'11622112000109');
11.622.112/0001-09
```

I tried something similar with **Python** using `%` operator

```
mask = '%s%s/%s%s/%s%s%s%s'
mask % ', '.join(list('13082004'))
```

But,

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string not enough arguments
>   for format string

I know why I am getting this error, but can pass this point. Any solution is welcome.

Comment: does the length or format change?

Comment: For a CNPJ, don't think so... (Código Nacional de Pessoa Jurídica)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With your syntax, you need to make a `tuple`, instead of a `join`ed comma-separated string, since the latter is treated as one supplied string argument, hence the error you're experiencing:

```
'%s%s/%s%s/%s%s%s%s' % tuple('13082004')
```

Or, use the newer string `.format()` method, with the `*` operator to unpack the string into multiple arguments:

```
'{}{}/{}{}/{}{}{}{}'.format(*'13082004')
```

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
mask = '%s%s/%s%s/%s%s%s%s'
mask % tuple('13082004')
```

running the code above will result in:

```
'13/08/2004'
```